# Can't create admin user on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am new to rails and I have gone through Kevin Skoglund's Ruby on Rails 3 Essential Training course on Lynda.com. Through the course you set up a simple cms, which I did. It doesn't cover Git or deployment but I've pushed my simple cms to github (https://github.com/nick5a1/Simple_CMS) and deployed to Heroku (http://nkarrasch.herokuapp.com/).

In order to deploy to Heroku I followed the Heroku setup guide (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3) and switched my database from MySQL to PostgreSQL. As instructed I changed gen'mysql2' to gen 'sqlite3' in my Gemfile and ran bundle install before pushing. I then ran `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

I'm running into 2 problems. When I try to log in (http://nkarrasch.herokuapp.com/access) I get an error "We're sorry, but something went wrong". I should instead be getting a flash message with invalid username/password combination. This is what I'm getting on my test environment on my local machine.

Secondly, when I log into the Heroku console to create and create an admin user, when I try to save that user I get the following error:

```
irb(main):004:0> user.save
   (1.2ms)  BEGIN
  AdminUser Exists (1.9ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."username" = 'Nick5a1' LIMIT 1
   (1.7ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
```

Any advice on how to troubleshoot would be greatly appreciated :).

Thanks very much,
Nick

EDIT: Here are my Heroku logs:

```
2012-06-27T20:36:44+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-06-27T20:37:34+00:00 heroku[api]: Add shared-database:5mb add-on by *
2012-06-27T20:37:34+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by *
2012-06-27T20:37:34+00:00 heroku[api]: Add RAILS_ENV, LANG, PATH, RACK_ENV, GEM_PATH config by *
2012-06-27T20:37:34+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by *
2012-06-27T20:37:34+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by *
2012-06-27T20:37:34+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 1d82839 by *
2012-06-27T20:37:35+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-06-27T20:37:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 45450`
2012-06-27T20:37:40+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-06-27T20:37:40+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-06-27T20:37:40+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-06-27T20:37:44+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:45450
2012-06-27T20:37:44+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-06-27T20:37:44+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-06-27T20:37:44+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2012-06-27T20:37:44+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-06-27T20:37:44+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-06-27 20:37:44] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2012-06-27T20:37:44+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-06-27 20:37:44] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2012-06-27T20:37:44+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-06-27 20:37:44] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=45450
2012-06-27T20:37:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-06-27T20:39:44+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Awaiting client
2012-06-27T20:39:44+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2012-06-27T20:39:44+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-06-27T20:39:51+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-06-27T20:39:51+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
2012-06-27T20:41:05+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Awaiting client
2012-06-27T20:41:05+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails console`
2012-06-27T20:41:05+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-06-27T20:46:09+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-06-27T20:46:09+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
```

Comment: Make sure to run `heroku logs` in console to see error reports that you get from visiting your app.  There will usually be enough detail there to point you to the problem.

Comment: @John is right, please provide the `heroku logs`. Also make sure you have `heroku run rake db:migrate`...

Comment: Thanks John, I've added my logs. There doesn't seem to be anything obvious in them?

Comment: hi Gabriel, migrations were run as soon as I deployed. I've re-run them and restarted the heroku server, still getting the same 2 errors.

Comment: I have answered for a possible problem, but you need to show the `heroku logs` after the error....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring two different databases... Try removing these two lines from your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'pg'
gem 'mysql2'
```

And adding the below:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'mysql2'
end
```

In this way you are defining one database to be used for development (`mysql`) and another one (`pg`) for production.

After changing the gemfile:

```
git add .
git commit -m "gemfile updated"
git push
git push heroku master
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

**EDIT** - looking at your `routes.rb` I realised that you are using the `match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'`, which will make all your actions available through `get` request. However, I have never used it and I think you might have a problem with your routes.

Jast to make sure that it is pointing to `access/attempt_login`, can you please include the the routes generated by:

```
rake routes
```

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense with different development and production databases. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same errors after doing the above. I've made the update on github also.